# Using T as a generic type to a known struct?

Tags: c#, generics, struct

Alright, so I have a known struct, which means, I already have members inside this struct... However, I have other structs that I wanna use in 1 function call.

This is the declaration of a function in some class:

```
public void OpenFile<T, F, U>(ref T body, ref F recordMap, ref U records);
```

And this is a call for the function in some other class:

```
OpenFile<SomeStructure1, SomeStructure2, SomeStructure3>(ref someStructureBodyDefinition, ref someStructureRecordMapDefinition, ref someStructureRecordsDefinition);
```

So, to dump it all down:

Can I use ANY struct for a function call in a generic type and if so, can you show me how to use members of the struct inside the function?

Comment: Your last question is "can you show me how to use members of the struct inside the function", by which I think you mean that you want do something like this inside the body of  your `OpenFile` method:  `var x = someStructureBodyDefinition.someMember`, i.e. you want to interact with a member of the struct.  However, you won't be able to do this, unless you know in advance that T has a member named `someMember`.  The way you can know this is by having T either implement a known interface or by having T inherit from a known base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use ANY struct for a function call in a generic type and if so, can you show me how to use members of the struct inside the function?

Okay, based on the edited question it seems you're trying to understand how to *use* an instance of a parameter of a generic method, where that parameter's type is one of the method's type parameters.

To do that, you need to be able to generalize that type parameter with a constraint. Since we are talking about a value type here (i.e. `struct`), the only such generalization possible would be for the type to implement an interface, and for that interface to be declared on the method as a constraint.

E.g.:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    void M1();
    string P1 { get; }
}

struct MyStruct : ISomeInterface { /* ... */ }

void Method<T>(T t) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    // can call M1:
    t.M1();

    // can get property value P1:
    string text = t.P1;
}
```

If you will be calling this method with different type parameters where the types do in fact implement a common interface, but are not actually declared as such (e.g. all the structs implement an `M1()` method, but there is no `ISomeInterface` and/or some or all of the structs aren't declared as implementing such an interface), then you could use `dynamic`, either in lieu of making that parameter use a generic type parameter at all, or assigning the passed-in value to a `dynamic` local variable and using that.

If there is no way to generalize the type being used, then you should rethink whether a generic method is really good design at all. It probably isn't in that scenario.